# What does the Q stand for in some built-in symbols?

Tags: syntax

What is the "Q" in built-in symbols such as FreeQ[expr, form], MemberQ[list, form]?
(Query?)

Thanks.

Comment: `Q` stands for `Query` or a `Question`. It returns `True` or `False`

Comment: `Names["*Q"]` will give you a list of query functions.